# android gridview, listview or other

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to achieve is a gridview, but only use 1 row and an indefinite number of columns.

Not sure how to explain... 3 items on screen with 10 or 20dp spacing, though the rest of the items (4,5,6,etc) are off screen. Then you can slide horizontally to the next. A bit like a web banner.

Though, i would like it to snap to each item of those 3.
So example you see 1,2 and 3.
Slide left slowly, moves 1, shows you 2,3 and 4.
Slide fast, move more items.

Pageflipper/viewflipper would show each 3, so would go from 1,2,3 to 4,5,6
Scrollview doesn't do snapping.
Gridview? If so, how?

What is the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing it through this [two way gridview](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview). I think it does what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're looking for, and I found two examples:

**Horizontal slide gallery with pages**
Imagine you want to create interactive horizontal slide gallery with paging (scroll left/right not one-by-one but pages).

[image]

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=678

**Horizontal Scrolling Pages of Images in Android**
How to have pages of images that scroll left and right. Each page contains a gridview and is controllable using a swipe gesture.

[image]
http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/horizontal-scrolling-pages/